# Solr schema.xml field confusion

Tags: solr

i m new to solr so i really need someone to help me understand the fields below. What's the meaning of the field if it's stored=false, indexed=false? see the two examples below, what's the differences? If the field is not stored, what's the use of it...

```
    <field name="test1" type="text" indexed="false"
        stored="false" required="false" />
```

How about this one?

```
    <field name="test2" type="text" indexed="false"
        stored="false" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If its not stored then you can't get the (indexed) value of that field in the results set (e.g. to display to user, like book title). If its not indexed then you cannot search against it. Not sure there is a point in having them both false (maybe if some field is used in a copyField, that is stored/indexed)?

Comment: nickdos, i doubted if this is needed at all so i posted this question :). Thanks for helping me~

Comment: As other posters have mentioned this information is easy to find on SOLR website - you are tempting negative ratings - as defined by SO as "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easier than it seems:

- `indexed`: you can search on it
- `stored`: you can show it within your search results

In fact, there might be fields that you don't use for search, but you just want to show them within the results. On the other hand, there might be fields that you want to show within the results but you don't want to use for search. The `stored=false` is important when you don't need to show a certain field, since it improves performance. If you make all your fields stored and you have a lot of fields, Solr can become slow returning the results.

Of course, having both false doesn't make a lot of sense, since the field would become totally useless.

The unique difference between your two fields is the `multiValued=true`, which means that the second field can contain multiple values. That means that the content of the field is not just a text entry but a list of text entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot, javanna! Your explanation makes a lot of sense to me now. The former dev left without documentation and I am new to this solr thing so I had to ask experts here to understand why he even had stored=false and index=false appeared for the same field in schema.xml. Clearly, this doesnt seem to be needed and I can simply remove it. I think if a field is not mentioned in the schema file, it will basically be ignored anyway, no need to do this bug-like thing to ignore a field...thanks a lot for helping me and guiding me :)

Comment: You're welcome! Just one more thing. You should check within your `schema.xml` if you're using dynamic fields, since that could make things a little bit different.

Comment: thanks javanna! This is very helpful :) Just to confirm, does it mean that if the field definition matches with the dynamic fields, then there is no need in the original field itself to define indexed and stored since dynamic field will do so?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you configure the dynamicField itself :) You can configure a pattern with wildcards and say: all fields that match must be indexed, stored, multivalued and so on...

Comment: Thanks a lot, javanna! I am running into another solr problem as a two-week solr developer, i have no idea on how to fix it, can you please help me take a look as well? link is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204602/solr-internal-server-error

Answer (score 9):

You can find best explanation from [Solr wiki.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml)

If you want a field to be searchable then you should set indexed attribute to true.

> indexed=true : True if this field should be "indexed". If (and only if) a field is indexed, then it is searchable, sortable, and facetable.

If you want to retrieve the field at the search result then you should set stored attribute to true.

> stored=true : True if the value of the field should be retrievable during a search

If you want to store multiple value in a single field then you should set multivalued field to true.

> multivalued=true : True if this field may contain multiple values per document, i.e. if it can appear multiple times in a document