# How to fix IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found?

Tags: solr

I write my own code to index some data files myself. It was all working. Once I modified the `schema.xml` file, now i get internal server error that i have no idea how to interpret it.

```
Internal Server Error

request: http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:249)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:54)
    at solr.client.SolrClient.index(SolrClient.java:109)
    at solr.client.SolrClient.main(SolrClient.java:26)
```

Then I look into catalina log file, it's saying that no core created...

```
   Jun 26, 2012 2:09:21 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore close
INFO: []  CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@5675b3ee
Jun 26, 2012 2:09:21 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.close(SolrCore.java:712)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:599)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:483)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:335)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:219)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Jun 26, 2012 2:09:21 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore closeSearcher
INFO: [] Closing main searcher on request.
Jun 26, 2012 2:09:21 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:600)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:483)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:335)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:219)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/Users/nan/solr-tomcat/solr/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@11396ef7: files: []
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1104)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:585)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/Users/nan/solr-tomcat/solr/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@11396ef7: files: []
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:667)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:72)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:375)
    at org.apache.solr.core.StandardIndexReaderFactory.newReader(StandardIndexReaderFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1093)
    ... 24 more
```

Updated catalina log file above...yes i removed the index data since i thought i am going to create new index...and i did this earlier today but i didnt see this kinda error until now...how should i fix this? :(

Thanks a lot!!! (^infinitive times)

Comment: There should be something more in your catalina log file, above what you posted. Can you post that fragment instead of the "No cores were created" one please?

Comment: thanks for offering help, javanna :). I just updated the log file in the question. The thing is i removed index file since i will re-run the index through my code...how should i fix this now? thanks!

Comment: @javanna i fixed this by copying some segment data (segments.gen and segments_2) from spellchecker directory to index directory..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover from Solr deleted index files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938691/how-to-recover-from-solr-deleted-index-files)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you can see from your log file Solr/Lucene can't find the segments file within the data directory.

If you remove the data directory, Solr will recreate a brand new index (empty, of course)automatically on startup. From the error it seems that your data directory is there, but with some file missing. Since I understood that you are willing to reindex everything, you can fix the error just deleting your index directory and then reindex.

Comment: i run into a strange solr exception today after i restart tomcat. basically my solr instance is no longer working. i am too new to this thing and have no idea on how to fix it. can you please help me take a look again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234132/strange-solr-exception

Comment: I'd like to add that removing the files within the `data/` directory might not be enough (what I tried at first). You need to remove the directory itself.

Answer (score 2):

Exception [IndexNotFoundException](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexNotFoundException.html) signals that no index was found in the Directory. Possibly because the directory is empty, however can also indicate an index corruption.

So you should:

1. Delete the `index` directory or restore data from backups.
2. Restart the server (or at least the reload the config).

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error because **there were no documents to search** yet (which happens on my workstation).

Triggering the creation of a document will fix the issue in this case.