# Caught between NoSuchDirectoryException and IndexNotFoundException

Tags: exception, solr, lucene, islandora

I'm trying to set up Islandora 7.1.3 as per https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/ISLANDORA713/Islandora. Fedora Commons and Drupal are working, but I'm having an issue with Solr 4.2/fedoragsearch 2.6.

Following the instructions at https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/ISLANDORA713/Installing+Solr+and+GSearch, I ran into a problem at step 14.

When I tried to update the index at [url]/fedoragsearch/rest?operation=updateIndex I got this error:

> IndexReader open error indexName=FgsIndex : ; nested exception is: org.apache.lucene.store.NoSuchDirectoryException: directory 'path/to/solr/collection1/data/index' does not exist

That seemed straightforward, so I shut down tomcat and created data/index within the existing collection1 directory. Restarting tomcat and trying again gave me:

> IndexReader open error indexName=FgsIndex : ; nested exception is: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory@/path/to/solr/collection1/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@68aed52c: files: []

A quick search for this error suggested if the index directory is present Solr expects it not to be empty, with the solution being to delete the directory and let Solr create it. But that gives me the previous error.

I've tried with and without the collection1/data directory present (NoSuchDirectoryException either way) and I've set the permissions on collection1 (and collection1/data, if present) to 777 while I try to work this out.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr - internal server error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204602/solr-internal-server-error)

Comment: @kenorb - Sounds like they may have already come upon that very question, to me.

Comment: @paddymcc - I've posted a community wiki answer based on your solution in the thread over on Google Groups.  If you wish to post your own answer, I'll gladly delete mine.  You deserve the rep for it.  Otherwise, don't hesitate to edit.

Answer (score 1):

The OP appears to have resolved this over on the [Islandora Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/islandora/oZv7EUk_Qy8/d8_0WRer4xoJ).

It seems it was caused by a mismatch between the the solrconfig.xml `DataDir`, and the location that gsearch was looking for the index:

> solrconfig.xml specified a dataDir at solr/data. gsearch was looking in solr/collection1/data.

A similar comment has since been posted by [Mark Jordan](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/~markj) on the Islandora guide:  https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/ISLANDORA713/Installing+Solr+and+GSearch

> Solution was to modify $FEDORA_HOME/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml:
>
> ```
> <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>
> ```
>
> should be
>
> ```
> <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:./solr/data}</dataDir>
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Basically the exception [NoSuchDirectoryException](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/NoSuchDirectoryException.html) is thrown when you try to use/list a non-existent directory, so you've to create it first.

And exception [IndexNotFoundException](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexNotFoundException.html) signals that no index was found in the Directory. Possibly because the directory is empty, however can also indicate an index corruption.

So in this case you should remove data directory and it'll be recreated on startup.